# Httpd Server-Status Apache 2.4 403

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403, rhel6

I have updated the httpd version from 2.2 to 2.4. The virtualhosts are working, but server-status keeps giving me 403 errors...

Configuation of VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myserver.com

   <Location /server-status>
      SetHandler server-status
      Require all granted
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Error in the log when i try to access server-status:

```
[Wed Feb 21 13:35:46.746710 2018] [core:error] [pid 29073:tid 139839416555264] (13)Permission denied: [client 10.100.00.00:60634] AH00035: access to /server-status denied (filesystem path '/etc/httpd/htdocs') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I already tried different settings in the virtualhost with deny and allow, but none of them helped me... Also chmod 777 on htdocs..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `mod_status` enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled!